# Fetch internal data from JSON

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I want to fetch inner data from JSON

I have JSON as

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "cusname": "KFC Inc.",
    "accno": "31926819",
    "billStatus": "Pending",
    "billID1": {
        "ID": "BILL232244",
        "month": "Aug",
        "amount": "400"
    },
    "billID2": {
        "ID": "BILL232244",
        "month": "Aug",
        "amount": "400"
    },
    "billID1Amount": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "4/Nov/2107"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "cusname": "KFC Inc.",
    "accno": "31926819",
    "billStatus": "Pending",
    "billID1": {
        "ID": "BILL232244",
        "month": "Aug",
        "amount": "400"
    },
    "billID2": {
        "ID": "BILL232244",
        "month": "Aug",
        "amount": "400"
    },
    "billID1Amount": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "4/Nov/2107"
}]
}
```

I want to extract all the values of ID of all billID1 or billID2 for all id in data jsonObject
for Example: I want to get BILL232244 for billID1 & BILL232244 for billID2 for "id":1 and same goes for "id":2

Please suggest logic.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) { System.out.println(data[i].ID) } ` this will give you what you want

Comment: It's not working

Comment: It's best to turn this into a java object first. You can use jackson to make a jsonnode, then get the nodes you want by walking the object tree using the keys.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) { System.out.println(data[i].billID1.ID);  System.out.println(data[i].billID2.ID) } ` In your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = root.getJSONArray("data");

 for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
// now loop the element:
JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

String idval = obj.getString("id"); 
String billid1 = obj.getString("billID1");
String billid2 = obj.getString("billID2"); 
}
```